# Why is my BASH script [script] producing a '[script]: command not found' error?

Tags: bash, scripts

I recently downloaded the newest tor-browser from the tor project. It's a zip, so I extracted it to `~/.tor-browser_en-US/`. I ran `./start-tor-browser.desktop --register`. Great - now I can open the application from GOME. But, I'm trying to write scripts for things. So, I create a script `~/.tor-browser_en-US/torbrowse` it looks like this:

```
#A simple run script for tor-browser
#created by hunter


#!/bin/bash/

#run startup script
sh -c '"/home/hunter/.tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/home/hunter/.tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k
```

then

`chmod 755 torbrowse`

When I run it via `./torbrowse`, it works great; tor-browser starts right up. So, I created `torb` - a symbolic link in a custom scripts directory I've included in my path: `~/.local/share/myscript`:

```
ln -s ~/.tor-browser_en-US/torbrowse ~/.local/share/myscript/torb
```

Here is where I run into confusion.

`$ torb` ---> `torbrowse: command not found`

Not really sure what is going on, nor where I went wrong. Any advice would help :)

edit 1: `~/.tor-browser_en-US/torbrowse` now looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash/

# A simple run script for tor-browser
# created by hunter


#run startup script
sh -c '"/home/hunter/.tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/home/hunter/.tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k
```

edit 2: ~/.tor-browser_en-US/torbrowse` now looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# A simple run script for tor-browser
# created by hunter


#run startup script
"/home/hunter/.tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/home/hunter/.tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach) dummy %k
```

Comment: The `#!/bin/bash` needs to be at the start of the file.

Comment: Made the adjustment and still the same stdout

Comment: no slash in the end of the shebang and there is no reason to call ```sh``` again.

Comment: made the adjustments, still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. I had preemptively created an alias `alias torb=torbrowse` in my `~/.bash_aliases` file. This was getting in the way of BASH seeing the symbolic link. Commenting out the alias fixed the issue!

```
$ torb
```

The above command now properly launches tor-browser

I guess something I can glean from this, that I didn't know before, is that aliases can produce this behavior in bash and can prevent scripts from being properly loaded into the environment.

Thanks for input everyone :)